# Windows - get a sound alert when site is back up

Tags: windows, ping, http

A particular https endpoint I'm interested in is down. 
I want a way to monitor when it comes back up, and get an audible alert when that happens. 
How do I do that in Windows?

Comment: Write a program that attempts to make an https connection to the address.  When the status goes from Red to Green (in other words from being down to being up) make it play a sound effect.

Comment: I could, but why bother? I like the power of Lego bricks - see my answer on how I did it.

Comment: You asked, "How do I do that in Windows?", I told you how I would do it.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while ($true) {if (Test-Connection -quiet 8.8.8.8) { [console]::beep() }}
```

EDIT: Sorry that was assuming that whole host down and that you had ping response from same host when up.  If you don't need to check the content of the HTTPS endpoint, then this should do it:

```
while ($true) {if ((Test-netConnection -ComputerName www.google.com -Port 443).TcpTestSucceeded) { [console]::beep() }}
```

Comment: We cant guess what thus code or script is. Please detail and explain it

Comment: It's powershell and pretty self-explanatory (but it ICMP-pings the host rather than trying a http connection). You could use Invoke-WebRequest instead of Test-Connection

Comment: This is way more straight-forward than my answer, so marked this as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

Another option: use [httping](https://www.vanheusden.com/httping/)

It has a version for Windows, nice colored output, and can beep:

```
httping --audible-ping --colors --url http://google.com
```

[image]

Comment: It's now also available from [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/): `> choco install httping`

Answer (score 1):

Regarding a beep in windows:
if you use:: start [/wait] AudioFile, eg sounds in %SystemRoot%\Media" it will open a media player, which will cause problems. You can play a .wav with vbs script, which still works in Windows 10v1803.
eg alarm05.vbs

```
' alarm sound
Set oVoice = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")
set oSpFileStream = CreateObject("SAPI.SpFileStream")
oSpFileStream.Open "C:\Windows\Media\Alarm05.wav"
oVoice.SpeakStream oSpFileStream
oSpFileStream.Close
```

call this from a bat eg beep.bat

```
:: start a VBScript
start "" alarm05.vbs
exit
```

Complete Webcheck Version with Powershell 
eg checksite.ps1 right-click 'run with powershell'

```
# https://www.dennis-stepp.com/post/uricheck/   ps by Dennis Eugene Stepp, Jr.

# First we create the request.
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.com')
# $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create('http://google.off')

# We then get a response from the site.
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()

# We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

If ($HTTP_Status -eq 200) {
    Write-Host "Site is OK!"
    [console]::beep(880,300)
}
Else {
    Write-Host "The Site may be down, please check!"
    [console]::beep(440,300)
}

# Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.
$HTTP_Response.Close()

pause
```

Comment: That answers only half of the question.

Answer (score 0):

### TL;DR

- Download [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html)
- run this in cmd.exe:

  ```
  c:\> echo echo ^G > beep.bat
  c:\> for /L %x in () do ( curl --insecure https://endpoi.nt > nul && call beep )
  ```

That's Ctrl-G. You can't copy that character from above, you actually need to type `Ctrl-G`

### Long story

I want to make this work from the command line.
There are a couple things to solve.

1. How to access an http(s) endpoint from cmd line?

   ```
   c:\> curl http://the.site
   ```

   Is it an https endpoint that's missing the correct certificates?

   ```
   c:\> curl --insecure https://the.site
   ```

   Skip the output?

   ```
   c:\> curl http://the.site > nul
   ```
2. How to make a sound from the command line?

   ```
   c:\> echo ^G
   ```

   That's Ctrl+G
3. How to conditionally beep when the `curl` comand succeeds?

   ```
   c:\> curl http://the.site && echo ^G
   ```

   What if you want the beep when it fails?

   ```
   c:\> curl http://the.site || echo ^G
   ```
4. How do you run something in a loop?

   Use `for /L %x in (start,step,end)` without specifying start, step, end:

   ```
   c:\> for /L %x in () do ( echo again )
   ```
5. Putting `echo ^G` inside the body of the loop outputs it to the console and thus makes a beep sound regardless of the `curl` command failing or not.
   We must therefore find a way to beep without directly outputting the `^G` character.

   ```
   c:\> echo echo ^G > beep.bat
   ```

   You can now make a beep sound just by calling `beep`.
6. Putting it all together:

```
c:\> for /L %x in () do ( curl --insecure https://endpoi.nt > nul && call beep )
```

Comment: I would suggest a few elaborations. (1) Keep a flag to remember the previous `curl` completion status, so that you beep only on a transition. (2) Add a delay into the loop to prevent high network traffic and CPU use. (3) Maybe use one beep for up, three for down (you will need a short pause between). (4) Instead of `Ctl-G`, you can get any sounds you want with `start [/wait] AudioFile`, eg sounds in `%SystemRoot%\Media`. PS Great profile image, though I prefer bass clef!

Comment: @AFH Very good suggestions! For my particular use case, I wanted 'infinite beeps' when site is up, because I used it as an alarm clock! The joys of being 24h on call... As for high network traffic - again, in my scenario - the endpoint was load-balanced on a cluster of 300 VMs x 12 cores that had gone down (ouch), so DoS-ing it from my laptop on a consumer network was hardly an issue :)

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use **Fping** (https://github.com/dexit/fping-windows) with the `-b` flag to beep every time you get a response:

```
fping.exe host.domain.com -b
```

You can also use `-b-` to get a beep every time the ping fails which is useful when you want to be notified when a host goes down:

```
fping.exe 12.34.56.67 -b-
```

Fping also supports pinging multiple hosts and logging to a file, avoiding the need to open multiple command prompts.

NOTE: this uses ICMP so only shows whether the host is up, not the actual HTTP(S) endpoint, but may still be useful depending on your needs.

Comment: I downloaded it from that link and the flag means something different: `-b, --size=BYTES   amount of ping data to send, in bytes (default: 56)`